# Sent crypto to email address, recipient's exchange needs transaction-id

Tags: exchanges

I sent $500 in Bitcoin and Ethereum to my niece email address. She got an email for each but could not cash them without Transaction Hash (TXN ID) as I was told by her exchange company! Is there any way I or she can get the money ($1000)? Appreciate help in advance!

Comment: Hi Naser, which company were you using to make your transfer? What did their support team say?

Comment: Note: When you use an exchange such as Coinbase to send Bitcoin to an email address, this is ["off-chain"](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/cryptocurrency-trading-pairs/how-to-send-and-receive-cryptocurrency) - it isn't a true Bitcoin transaction and doesn't have a BItcoin transaction-ID (transaction-hash). The recipient probably needs an account on the same exchange.

Comment: What do you mean by "her exchange company"? What relationship does this company have to the transfers you made to her?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. She is in overseas with company named Wallex (Form screen shots she sent me)! Can she open a Coinbase account even now (10 days later) and any hope to collect the money? Coinbase can't help (sounds like get lost). NOT happy at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to send Bitcoin to someone is to send it to a Bitcoin address, not to an email address. This means the transaction is handled by the Bitcoin network and has a Bitcoin transaction-ID (transaction-hash).

When you use an exchange such as Coinbase to send Bitcoin to an email address, this is ["off-chain"](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/cryptocurrency-trading-pairs/how-to-send-and-receive-cryptocurrency) - it isn't a true Bitcoin transaction and doesn't have a Bitcoin transaction-ID (transaction-hash).

The recipient probably needs an account on the same exchange. Only the exchange can advise whether opening an account will allow the receipt of money sent to an email address weeks earlier.

Comment: I have sent $ to her a couple years ago using her Bitcoin address before, (Coinbase Pro). However, the software was discontinued. I contacted Coinbase support and explained  and provide a copy of screen shot that will not allowing me using bit coin address. I was advised to use her email address which I did and the Submit button became "Enable". Then, my niece forwarded me the emails that she received from Coinbase. I assumed that all went well. Next day, she contacted me and saying her company needs TXN ID! Coinbase (chat) said no hope (Nature of Crypto) and hung up! Bad support and deal.

Comment: Yes, personally I would never give money to an exchange to look after for me medium to long term. I would always keep the money myself in a normal non custodial wallet instead.

Comment: She just sent me an email that she tried to open an account with Coinbase but coinbase told her where she resides opening account is prohibited/Restricted! Please help!

Comment: I realized that now. But what can I do to get that money back? It supposed to help with medical expenses. I have to get that back. Coinbase is not helping and I'm thinking to put complain with FTC, FCC, etc.

Comment: Since Coinbase have the money, only they can give it back. No one else can. However there are several aspects of your situation that are warning signs of a scam:  Your niece is far away, She urgently needs money, she cannot use normal methods to receive money. I would check with my niece through some other method than those used recently, maybe through relatives or friends that live near her. For example, her email account may have been hacked by scammers.

Comment: Coinbase branch in USA confirmed the $ is her account. NO scam. But because she is in overseas it falls under Coinbase in Germany (her VPN). However, because geographically she is in prohibited country (Iran), her account is restricted and cannot get it. She has contacted the Coinbase branch in Germany and was told I need to be contacting them, while USA branch telling me because she's the account holder she is the one to contact them. They just giving us running around (bureaucracy at best). SO frustrated. I'm not going to give up. Thanks for trying to help.